# Track iOS App Store Sales

Tags: ios

Is it possible to get an alert every time my app sells?  Like to have a counter at my desk seeing them realtime?

I'm guessing someone has cracked this already, and can maybe recommend hardware to hook up to it as well?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming-related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible, because Apple does not provide/allow any such thing.

But, as a solution I can suggest something. It is not so pretty but it can serve the purpose. Considering its obvious to start the app after download. You can have some server call which updates your database table and at the same time firing you an email that the new app download has happened. You can create one web service and can run it when app gets opened first time.

Comment: Ok, now that's interesting.

Comment: Please don't do any of this. As a user, I don't want an app I install to waste my data just to tell the developer the app has been run. As a developer, I can wait once a day to see a report from Apple of the previous day's sales.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the number of downloads from Apple's [iTunes connect](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-analytics/). As of now, there is no ready to go way, but I'm sure that you can use the data from this site and create a counter for yourself.

Comment: Any ideas on how to extract it in a usable form?